# Set a default variable value in a dynamic function

Tags: php

I will create a dynamic function. I created it, but I want now set a default dynamiclly value in this function :

```
  $functionName = "obj_".$type.$action;
  $function = "obj".$action;
  $GLOBALS[$functionName] = function() {
    $function($type);
  };
```

And I want this result after générating the function :

```
$functionName = "obj_article_add";
  $function = "obj_add";
  $obj_article_add = function() {
    obj_article_add("article");
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Specific approach

If I understood correctly, you're trying to do something like this:

```
function create_action_for($action, $type)
{
  $function_name = 'obj_' . $action;
  return function () use ($function_name, $type) {
    $function_name($type);
  };
}

$obj_add_article = create_action_for('add', 'article');

$obj_add_article();
```

**Demo here: https://3v4l.org/48jbd**

### More generic approach (PHP 7.1+)

Here's a far more generic approach that takes a function name and a default value and returns a function that passes that value as its first parameter, while allowing subsequent parameters:

```
function create_action_for($function_name, $first_param_value)
{
  return function (...$args) use ($function_name, $first_param_value) {
    return $function_name($first_param_value, ...$args);
  };
}

function obj_add($type, $param1, $param2)
{
  echo 'adding ', $type, ' with ', $param1, ' and ', $param2;
}

$obj_add_article = create_action_for('obj_add', 'article');

$obj_add_article('something', 'stuff');
```

**Demo here: https://3v4l.org/kmTpC**

Comment: The PHP way is probably more like `$function_name($first_param_value, ...$args)`, nowadays.

Comment: @Blackhole You're completely right, just edited the answer.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for thank you very much!